# How do I write a line to a text file whenever data is inserted into a database?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

If I insert to database like this:
`insert into MyTbl (A,B) values ('1','2')`

I need to insert into a text file like this:
`SW.writeline('1','2')......`.

I need to make sure that the text file will always be updated when data is inserted. What is the best and fastest way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to edit your question: writing a line to a text file is one task, inserting data into a database is a different task. I assume your database is Sql CE, but you should specify it.

Comment: sounds like you want to log every insert into the database into a text file... if so could you edit your question to be a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to write to a text file or are you just trying to get logging into another database?

Use a trigger to insert the text you want to write into a separate logging table. Then have a periodic task which reads the logging table and does whatever you need with it, be it writing to a text file or copying to another database.

Comment: Although they haven't specified the database they are using, as it's Windows Mobile it's probably SqlServerCE which doesn't support triggers. Even if it's something else, it's very rare for a small, light-weight database (such as you'd typically use on a mobile device) to support triggers. - I'm not aware of any that do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a SqlCommand, you can subscribe to the StatementCompleted event.  However, the event args won't show you what you just inserted.

Another approach could be to just have your sw.WriteLine(..) fire off immediately after your insert command.  You could always wrap a transaction around it to make sure to two stay in sync.